# Number Theory: which primes are a sum of two squares?

Tags: number-theory

Problem: show that if the prime $p = a^2 + 5b^2$ then $p \equiv 1 \textrm{ or } 9 \pmod{20}$.

Is there any other way to prove this other than to check each case $p = 1, \ldots, 19 \pmod{20}$ and show that only 1 and 9 work?

Comment: You might want to look about Gaussian Integers and it's primes.

Comment: see it http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606547.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at $p \pmod{4}$ and at $p \pmod{5}$ separately to cut down slightly on the case analysis.